# Se pueden contener clases dentro de clases en CSS?

Tags: css, css3

tengo una duda con CSS:
La principal y obvia forma para las clases es así

```
.content {
    color:white;
}
.content .title {
    font-size: 72px;
}
```

por ejemplo, pero me ha despertado la curiosidad el si se puede hacer esto:

```
.content {
    color:white; 
    .title {
        font-size:72px;
    }
}
```

Gracias

Comment: La respuesta corta: no. Es una violación a la sintaxis del *lenguaje* de CSS. Sólo se permite el `nesting` o anidado para cierto tipo de reglas y de una forma particular. Puedes leer la documentación en [sintaxis CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Sintaxis). Saludos

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, agradecería que lo hubieras puesto en respuestas pero ya la han puesto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si. Se puede hacer lo que decis pero deberias usar SASS. Este te permite programar y re utilizar los estilos de forma más eficiente, este link es el oficial https://sass-lang.com/ y acá te dejo un ejemplo de lo que vos preguntaste https://codepen.io/kusillus/pen/vyNjvK

Espero que esto te sirva :D Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias :D. De hecho estoy usando sass, solo que no lo he aclarado ya que me interesaba saber si era principalmente compatible en css, pero siendo compatible con sass no tengo por que preocuparme :D

Answer (score 1):

no, no se puede debido a que al especificar la clase que vas a tratar solo modificaras esa si agregas una clase mas adentro simplemente las instrucciones dadas de diseño no se daran debido a que dentro de las llaves solo se puede poner contenido css otra manera de hacerlo seria:

```
.btn-primary{
    float: right;
    padding: 7px;
    background-color: #B71C1C;
    color: #FFF; 
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.btn:hover{
background-color: #F44336;
}
```

espero haberte ayudado

Comment: Muchas gracias por aclarar mi duda principal :D (No tenia mas, pero una persona me ha aclarado como puedo usarlo así)
PD: Veo que eres nuevo, bienvenido :)

Comment: Gracias por la bienvenida! y fue un placer aclararte tu duda :D